# Parsing JSON using RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit

I have been using RestKit for sometime but some APIs have changed in the latest version and I'm no longer able to parse simple JSON.

Here's the payload I have:

```
{
   "result":true,
   "items":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "receiver":"11011101"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "receiver":"11011101"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I parse the contents of the "items" dictionary as instances of the object Conversation I have created?

Using the code below doesn't work (objects are never mapped):

```
RKObjectMapping* conversationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Conversation class]];
[conversationMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"id"];
[conversationMapping mapKeyPath:@"receiver" toAttribute:@"receiver"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:conversationMapping forKeyPath:@"items"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/getConversations" delegate:self];
```

Conversation class

```
@interface Conversation : NSObject {
    NSString *id;
    NSString *receiver; }

+ (void)objectMapping;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *id; @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *receiver;

@end

@implementation Conversation
@synthesize id;
@synthesize receiver;


+ (void)objectMapping {
    RKObjectMapping* conversationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Conversation class]];
    [conversationMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"id"];
    [conversationMapping mapKeyPath:@"receiver" toAttribute:@"receiver"];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:conversationMapping forKeyPath:@"items"];
}

@end
```

Comment: show your `Conversation` class

Comment: maybe you should use jsonkit directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was something totally not related to RestKit. The content type of the response coming back from the server was not set to JSON, after fixing that object mapping worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

How is your root object defined (the one that holds "result" and your Conversation "items")? That should look something like this:

@interface MyResponse

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* items;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL result;

with the appropriate mapping for that as well.